# java web services

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans

I am new to java web services and I want to ask about the following

I would like to build a web services for existing web page (existing in the internet I did not build it)

to allow client to search through the containt of the web page

what steps can I follow ? I would like to use net beans if there are examples for it

Answer (score 3):

That is not what Java Web Services means. It deals with servers and clients that are specifically made for programmatic access to data. What you need is a content scraper, that accesses pages made for human consumption and extracts useful data.

Look at the [screen-scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/screen-scraping) and [webscraping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/webscraping) tags here for some starting points.